# writing siddhi custom function/stream extension getting neither a function extension nor an aggregated attribute extension

Tags: siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I am new to `WSO2 Sp` and `siddhi`.

I am trying to create custom siddhi extension. I used the below archetype to generate the skeleton extension and i tried modifying the function and streamfunction class.

`mvn archetype:generate     -DarchetypeGroupId=org.wso2.siddhi.extension.archetype     -DarchetypeArtifactId=siddhi-archetype-execution     -DgroupId=org.wso2.extension.siddhi.execution     -Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`

I built the jar after making code changes and deployed the jar in the path `$WSO2_SP_HOME/lib`. But when I refer my function in the `siddhi` file as below, am getting error.

```
select newns:conv(inValue) as sinValue
insert into OutputStream;
```

Error is as follows:

```
[2020-02-03 13:44:23,042] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.StreamProcessorDeployer} - org.wso2.siddhi.core.exception.SiddhiAppCreationException: Error on 'TestCustomApp' @ Line: 12. Position: 26, near 'newns:conv(inValue)'. 'conv' is neither a function extension nor an aggregated attribute extension org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.exception.SiddhiAppDeploymentException: org.wso2.siddhi.core.exception.SiddhiAppCreationException: Error on 'TestCustomApp' @ Line: 12. Position: 26, near 'newns:conv(inValue)'. 'conv' is neither a function extension nor an aggregated attribute extension
        at org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.StreamProcessorDeployer.deploySiddhiQLFile(StreamProcessorDeployer.java:106)
        at org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.StreamProcessorDeployer.deploy(StreamProcessorDeployer.java:330)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngine.lambda$deployArtifacts$0(DeploymentEngine.java:291)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngine.deployArtifacts(DeploymentEngine.java:282)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.RepositoryScanner.sweep(RepositoryScanner.java:112)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.RepositoryScanner.scan(RepositoryScanner.java:68)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngine.start(DeploymentEngine.java:121)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngineListenerComponent.onAllRequiredCapabilitiesAvailable(DeploymentEngineListenerComponent.java:216)
        at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupComponentManager.lambda$notifySatisfiableComponents$7(StartupComponentManager.java:266)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
        at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupComponentManager.notifySatisfiableComponents(StartupComponentManager.java:252)
        at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupOrderResolver$1.run(StartupOrderResolver.java:204)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: org.wso2.siddhi.core.exception.SiddhiAppCreationException: Error on 'TestCustomApp' @ Line: 12. Position: 26, near 'newns:conv(inValue)'. 'conv' is neither a function extension nor an aggregated attribute extension
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.ExpressionParser.parseExpression(ExpressionParser.java:415)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SelectorParser.getAttributeProcessors(SelectorParser.java:211)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SelectorParser.parse(SelectorParser.java:89)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:115)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SiddhiAppParser.parse(SiddhiAppParser.java:245)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:65)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:74)
        at org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.StreamProcessorService.deploySiddhiApp(StreamProcessorService.java:100)
        at org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.StreamProcessorDeployer.deploySiddhiQLFile(StreamProcessorDeployer.java:94)
        ... 14 more
```

I can also extract the jar file contents and see the annotation folder contains `org.wso2.siddhi.annotation.Extension` file which has my class name.

Not sure what else is missing. Please help here.

Comment: Please share the complete stacktrace you are observing.

Comment: updated full error trace. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Check the @Extension() annotation is correct in your class, the namespace has to be "newns" while name is "conv" https://github.com/siddhi-io/siddhi-execution-list/blob/master/component/src/main/java/io/siddhi/extension/execution/list/IsEmptyFunctionExtension.java#L42

Also, note you should have implemented Function class